# poll system for Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, plugins, walkthrough

I want to make a poll system into my website like `http://dilemmaplugin.com/`, this is what I want but is just for Wordpress...

I don't know if there is some plugin for Symfony2, I've searched but nothing... So I would like to ask you a walkthrough about how to make it, using caché/ip for not voting twice... This is where I'm lost, the vote is basic, I think:

Database would be like

```
id     question              option_a       option_b
1      PS4 or Xbox One?      1523           1102
```

So if you press the two buttons, option fields will do +1, easy as ABC, but what about the caché/ip preventing duplicate votes?

I was also thinking about making some carousel div that contains random votes when you press `next` but that can be done via Json I think, just querying the DB with Ajax...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want/need to stick with your current schema, one way of preventing duplicate votes by IP Address is that you could use something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/)(very fast) and for each vote store the question id and the ip address. If your using Doctrine as your ORM then you could use a [preUpdateEvent](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) to check for the existence of the ip address.

You could setup a custom [Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) on your entity to check for the ip address as well which has the benefit of presenting friendly messages to your forms.

Another possibility is to setup an [Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) in your controller or model manager to check for the ip address.

Hope that gets you going in some decent direction.